# Drawing a scatterplot with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, graphics

How should I best approach drawing a scatter plot diagram in Cocoa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) offers scatter plots.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to create a custom subclass of NSView and override the `drawRect:` method.

You can draw primitives using many of [NSBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s class methods such as `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` and `strokeLineFromPoint:toPoint:`